# React.Component Syntax Error on creating div element

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Got an issue React.Component:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>
            );
    }
}
export default App;
```

When i run the project and check the Inspect Elements the error shows

> /App.js Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError:
>   D:\Test\reactApp\App.js: Unexpected token (5:9)

```
 3 |     render() {
  4 |         return(
> 5 |           <div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>
    |           ^
  6 |           );
  7 |     }
  8 | }
```

My Question is:
Is the `div` elements cannot be done to that particular Component?

I've done searching [Here](https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/) but `div` elements exists.

What did i missed up?

Comment: do you have added the react preset to your babel loader or did you maybe forget to import React?

Comment: My .babelrc looks like this `"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]`

Comment: How do u created project.Is it using create-react-app or custom seed?

Comment: Installing my project something like `>npm install babel-core --save-dev
 >npm install babel-loader --save-dev
 >npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev
 >npm install babel-preset-react --save-dev
 >npm install html-webpack-plugin --save-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to your babel presets: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react

As an alternativ you could try using [parceljs](https://parceljs.org/), it comes with all presets preinstalled.

Comment: Thanks @Nikita Malyschkin let me try this.